# Several images are displayed in one <img> tag that's changeable via JavaScript - is that OK for those images to be indexed by Google?

Tags: seo, image-search, google-image-search

I have a page which should contain text and several images related to this text.

I'd like to show only one image on the page and let the user change the image by clicking a "->" button (via JavaScript).

1. Will all of those images be indexed by Google (and others)?
2. How will Google decide which image to show to the user, as they all have the same position on the page, same text, description and other tags?

Or could you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Do this in reverse: show all the images, and via JavaScript (onload) hide the ones you don't need.

As for telling Google what image to use, you can do such things with structured data - see [this](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/?hl=en) for guided help with that.

Comment: Thank you all for:
1) idea to show all images first and hide ones upon page load complete
2) for pointing me to such a great Google's tool

Comment: @RomanMatveev No problem. Remember to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.